Cambiar el color de fondo de una Celda en QTableWidget
Tengo este codigo el cual es una QTableWidget y la primera columna esta con QCheckBox, lo que trato de hacer es que al seleccionar un checkbox o varios se cambie el color de fondo a color amarillo y cuando se deseleccione en color rojo, pero sucede lo contrario, es decir cuando selecciono cambia color rojo y cuando deselecciono sigue de color rojo.
Les agradeceria que me ayuden a resolver este problema.
Este es el codigo:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QCheckBox, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QBrush, QColor

import sys
import random

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('QTableWidget Example with CheckBox')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        # Create the table widget
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(10)  
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(5)  

        # Set column headers
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Select', 'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4'])

        # Fill the table with random data
        for row in range(10):
            # Add CheckBox to the first column
            check_box = QCheckBox()
            check_box.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, row=row: self.handleCheckboxChange(state, row))
            widget = QWidget()
            layout = QVBoxLayout()
            layout.addWidget(check_box)
            layout.setAlignment(check_box, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
            widget.setLayout(layout)
            self.table_widget.setCellWidget(row, 0, widget)

            for col in range(1, 5):
                random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(random_number))
                item.setBackground(QBrush(QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white))) 
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, col, item)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

    def handleCheckboxChange(self, state, row):
        # Obtain the checkbox widget from the cell
        widget_item = self.table_widget.cellWidget(row, 0)
        if widget_item:
            if state == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.yellow)
            else:
                color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.red)

            for col in range(1, self.table_widget.columnCount()):
                item = self.table_widget.item(row, col)
                if item:
                    item.setBackground(QBrush(color))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



Si siempre tiene color rojo es porque state nunca tiene el valor Qt.CheckState.Checked y, por tanto, siempre entra al else del if. Si ejecutas paso a paso, o si lo imprimes a la consola, ¿qué valor tiene state? ¿none?

El problema es que el argumento state generado por la señal stateChanged es un entero (2 para el caso de que el CheckBox esté seleccionado) en vez del enum. Esto hace que la igualdad jamás se cumpla.
Tienes varias opciones:

Usar directamente el valor entero (la más directa, pero no la más adecuada):
if state == 2:


Obtener el valor del enum mediante el atributo value y compararlo con state.
if state == Qt.CheckState.Checked.value:


Convertir el entero state a Qt.CheckState antes de comparar:
if Qt.CheckState(state) == Qt.CheckState.Checked:



Personalmente me gusta usar match-case en estos casos:
match Qt.CheckState(state):
    case Qt.CheckState.Checked:
        color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.yellow)
    case Qt.CheckState.Unchecked:
        color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.red)

o:
match Qt.CheckState(state):
    case Qt.CheckState.Checked:
        color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.yellow)
    case _:  # Cualquier otra cosa
        color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.red)


Fue la solucion al problema FJSevilla, fue muy acertada tu respuesta
